# Slicing vector field in $\mathbb{R}^3$ into vector fields in the plane.

Tags: vectors, vector-analysis

I am trying to draw the vector field $\mathbf{F}_1 = (-y, x, 0)$ in $\mathbb{R}^3$. Seeing that the third component of the field is zero I was wondering whether I could interpret this field as separate layered fields in the $\mathbb{R}^2$ as $\mathbf{F}_2 = (-y, x)$?

Comment: Yes, you could think about it that way. In each layer of $z=z_0$, it is a field as in $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer, I can't upvote you because of < 15. Have a good day!